# GUI loops and another loops

Tags: python, loops, cpu, infinite-loop

I confused about loops. For example in python3:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
....
....

while True:
    ....
    ....
    pygame.display.update()
```

When i use this, the program using, about %110 CPU. But when i use a GUI toolkit like tkinter:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
....
....
....
root.mainloop()
```

It using about %0.3 CPU. I think both are infinite loops. How can I optimize the first code?

Comment: What do you inside the while loop?

Comment: There is no difference between just print("smt") or a few lines command. Both are using %94 - %110 - %120 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is, that your typical GUI toolkit will blockingly wait for the arrival of new events and the loop body, including drawing operations, only gets executed in reaction to such events.

A typical game loop however does not wait for events to arrive, since there's a simulation going on, that needs to update continuously followed by updating the display.

I.e. the pygame loop is designed to use up as much CPU cycles as possible, to give the most smooth simulation. The tkinter loop however is designed to spend as much CPU cycles as possible to conserve system resources.

Comment: So this usage is normal isn't this?

Comment: @RichardBrook: It is to be expected. You can of course always wait for events in pygame, too: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait